# Actions to take against parcel delivery service that lost my parcels

Tags: united-kingdom, property, postal-service

I sent five parcels using a UK parcel delivery service called parcelhero. The parcels were collected by parcelforce UK. Only 1 of the parcels was delivered, another was returned to sender, and three are still missing. The phone number of the parcel delivery service does not work, and chasing parcelforce UK is futile. The missing parcels contained valuable items such as a passport, notebooks etc.

Considering one of the missing parcels contained a passport, what kind of action can I take against the parcel delivery service?

Comment: If you haven't done so already, [report the passport lost](https://www.gov.uk/report-a-lost-or-stolen-passport). And check your home or motor insurance policies; they may have cover for lost postage.

Answer (score 3):

### None

You broke your contract with ParcelHero - they could take action against you.

You say you sent a passport, which is clearly on the list of [prohibited items](https://www.parcelhero.com/en-gb/terms/prohibited-items) and this makes it an Undeliverable Consignments. And “Customer shall be liable at all times for any and all Charges incurred by PH in returning, storing or disposing of an Undeliverable Consignment.”

Comment: Okay, but how exactly could they take action against me. Adding that would improve your answer.

Comment: 2nd paragraph, quoted sentence